# Racket Binary Addition

Tags: binary, sum, racket, addition

I have a question concerning Racket.
Given 2 string binary numbers, I would like to obtain their sum in a string binary number. The function should take into account carry bits and a possible overflow.
So the function should look like this:

```
(define (binary-sum a b) ...)
```

For example:

```
(binary-sum "010" "001")

"011"
```

Or:

```
(binary-sum "0010" "1011")

"1101"
```

Or in case of overflow:

```
(binary-sum "1111" "0001")

"overflow"
```

Please identify any packages I need.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary values in Racket are specified using the prefix `#b`. Using that, we can create the following function:

```
> (define (binary-sum a b)
  (+ (string->number (string-append "#b" a))
     (string->number (string-append "#b" b))))

> (binary-sum "010" "001")
3
```

To format the output as binary as well, we can use `~r`, like so:

```
> (define (binary-sum a b)
  (~r (+ (string->number (string-append "#b" a))
      (string->number (string-append "#b" b))) #:base 2))

> (binary-sum "010" "001")
011
```

And finally, to add your overflow feature, we can simply compare the length of our result as a string to the length of one of the parameters.

```
(define (binary-sum a b)
  (let ((sum (~r (+ (string->number (string-append "#b" a))
                    (string->number (string-append "#b" b)))
                 #:base 2)))
    (if (> (string-length sum)
           (string-length a))
        "overflow"
        sum)))
```

Which behaves exactly as your question specifies. Let me know if you have any remaining doubts or confusion. Good luck!

Edit: Just wanted to note that if you ever need to merely add two binary values and don't mind getting an integer back, you can always just do it like so:

```
> (+ #b010 #b001)
3
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps me a lot! One more question, how can I fix the error message "read-syntax: `#lang` not enabled" when I run your last code?

Comment: @David `#lang` tells DrRacket what language we are using. But if you are running the code in the REPL or somewhere other than the DrRacket definitions window you can just ignore that line. I've edited my answer to not even include it.